# Is there a way to set certain MSbuild General rule properties for all project configurations in a .props file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to set default property values such as **Configuration Type** for all configurations of my Visual Studio project through the .props file for the project, but they aren't being applied. I can set the values of other General properties like **Intermediate Directory** successfully through the .props file. Using the **Configuration Type** property as an example, I'm also able to modify this property in the .vcxproj file on a per-configuration basis (Setting the property under a PropertyGroup specifying the configuration using a condition).

When looking at the property page for the .props file in Visual Studio, I suspect that I'm not able to set certain properties for all configurations because there is no corresponding setting.
[Property page for the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5DJb.png) [Property page for the .props file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abga5.png). I've also tried just manually editing the .props file to add this property, but it doesn't get applied:

```
<ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
```

After adding the above line and setting the property value from Visual Studio to , it still defaults To Application (.exe).

Is there a way to set these properties for all configurations in the project so that each individual configuration does not have to specify these properties individually in the .vcxproj file?

Comment: 'it still defaults To Application (.exe).' that's in the UI though, but does it also build a .exe? I mean it's possible to specify this in a property sheet, but VS might ignore that whereas msbuild will use it.

Comment: Yes, it then tries to build a .exe. I can look in the .vcxproj and its corresponding property group has been changed. I guess the problem can be rephrased to ask whether I can get a project or configuration to default the Configuration Property to StaticLibrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order in which things are evaluated. If you make a .props which sets `ConfigurationType` it needs to be imported *before* the `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />` line. VS will still ignore it, showing whatever is configured in the PropertyGroup with Configuration Label, but it will change what gets built.

That's not really nice, and indicates it's also not how you're supposed to do things, so what you could do instead is modify this section of the .vcxproj:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />

<Import Project="my.props" Condition="Exists('my.props')" />
<!-- Supply default in case property sheet not found
     and if not passed via /p:MyConfigurationType=xxx or similar -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyConfigurationType Condition="'$(MyConfigurationType)' == ''">StaticLibrary</MyConfigurationType>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
  <ConfigurationType>$(MyConfigurationType)</ConfigurationType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm not sure it's worth it though. Normally if you want to change the configuration type you select a different configuration/platform combination. The actual type chosen is something you change only once for each project usually, the above is more work.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I agree that it's probably not worth it. Would another solution be to clone $(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props, edit the default values, and import this new .props file in the .vcxproj instead?

Comment: That's pretty much the same principle as importing my.props: suppose you do that, the .vcxproj is (by default) still going to have those PropertyGroups with `Label="Configuration"` which is what VS uses for it's UI and which would override whatever is in Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props unless you also modify this manually. What you could do though is clone or modify the default C++ project template(s) (i.e. what you get for File->New Project) and then make them use StaticLibrary as default.

Comment: Okay that should be enough information going forward. Thank you again for your assistance!

Comment: Hi @ArmaanBandali, please do not forget to [accept the useful answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will benefit other members, have a nice day:)